# jQuery Fancy Toggle Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, toggle

I have a set of links that I'm trying to conceal inside a toggle , but my code below is not doing it . Please what have I done wrong.
Thank you.

```
        <script>
                $("#navigation li a[id]").click(function()) {
                     $("#" + this.id.substr(1)).slideToggle(600).siblings('.toggleDiv').slideUp(600);
                });
        </script>


         <div id="search" class="toggleDiv" style="display:none">List</div>  
                <div id="sidebar">
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="bios.php?id=1">President</a></li>
                            <li><a href="bios.php?id=2">Vice</a></li>
                            <li><a href="bios.php?id=3">Secretary</a></li>
                        </ul>      
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Brackets in jQuery are for attributes.

`a[id]` will not work because those `a` tags don't have an `id` attribute. You also don't have a `#navigation` div.

Try `$("#sidebar ul li a")`

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `)`.

```
$("#" + this.id.substr(1))
                 //  ----^
```

However your selector doesn't select the anchor elements as they don't have ID attributes and  `this.id` is `undefined`. It seems you want to get the id parameter of `href` attribute.

```
$("#sidebar li a").click(function()) {
    $("#"+this.href.slice(-1)).slideToggle(600).siblings('.toggleDiv').slideUp(600);
});
```